# is it possible to add text next to a string counter?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm making a game to test out my programming knowledge and I want to know if it would be  possible to add text next to the string counter  I made. I don't know where to do it and how to do it and I'm scared to ruin my code.

`def draw_counters(kills):
    screen.draw.text(str(kills), fontsize=40, center=CENTER, color=FONT_COLOR)`

Here is the full code if you need it

````
import math
import random

WIDTH = 800
HEIGHT = 600
CENTER_X = WIDTH/2
CENTER_Y = HEIGHT/2
CENTER = (CENTER_X, CENTER_Y)
FONT_COLOR = (255, 0, 0)
MOVE_DISTANCE = 5
kills = 0


game_over = False

fly = Actor("fly")

def draw():
    screen.clear()
    fly.draw()
    draw_counters(kills)

def place_fly():
    fly.x = CENTER_X
    fly.y = CENTER_Y

def draw_counters(kills):
    screen.draw.text(str(kills), fontsize=40, center=CENTER, color=FONT_COLOR)

def update():
    if keyboard.right:
        fly.x += MOVE_DISTANCE
        if fly.x > WIDTH:
            fly.x = WIDTH
    elif keyboard.left:
        fly.x -= MOVE_DISTANCE
        if fly.x < 0:
            fly.x = 0
    elif keyboard.down:
        fly.y += MOVE_DISTANCE
        if fly.y > HEIGHT:
            fly.y = HEIGHT
    elif keyboard.up:
        fly.y -= MOVE_DISTANCE
        if fly.y < 0:
            fly.y = 0

def on_mouse_down(pos):
    global kills
    if fly.collidepoint(pos):
        kills += 1
        place_fly()

place_fly()

pgzrun.go()```
````

Comment: Why would it not be possible? `screen.draw.text(str(kills)+"whatever you want", ...`, or `"%d kills" % kills"`, or `f"{kills} and counting"` – and so on.

Comment: Yeah, as you can see I'm still new at programming, I was just wondering if I did the formatting right or if It had to be typed in a different way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you could just do either:

- String concatenation: `"Text: " + str(kills)`
- String formatting:`"Text: %d" % kills`
- String interpolation: `f'Text: {kills}'`

String concatenation is just like "adding" two strings together.

String formatting replaces every format specification, for example `%d`, with the value after the %. In this case `%d` means to insert the decimal representation of an integer.

String interpolation essentially inserts what's inside {} in your string.